# Why can't we record amp sounds from line out of amps when we can hear in headphones using line out?

Tags: electromagnetism, sound, music

Suppose there is electric guitar, and we connect it to amplifier (amp). When we connect our headset into line out of the amp, we can hear what we are playing. If so, why can't we record the sound out of line out to sound card in computer using computer software?

Comment: Who says we can't do that? I'm pretty sure we can.

Comment: I heard that we require virtual software amps - if that is true, why is it the case when we can hear what we play by line out? That is my question. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention computers yet now you are talking about virtual software amps.

Comment: fixed the question.

Comment: What does this have to do with Electrical Engineering?

Comment: Wouldn't electrical engineering be the closet one related to this? I don't see any stackexchange that would be better to ask...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the line-in on my PC for recording my guitars, my piano, my microphone and my drum-kit. They all go into a mixer and ITS line-out connects to my PC's line-in. In fact I've just checked the headphone socket of my mixer and this also feeds stuff that I can record on my PC.

It works every time so to answer your question... You are mistaken - **we CAN record the sound out of line out to sound card in computer using computer software**!